# Can 眼镜 be translated with "eye" or "eyes"?

Tags: translation

On Duolingo, a question shows a green paint can, an ear, and an eye, and it asks:

> Which one of these is "eye"?

However, under the eye image is the text "眼镜". The dictionaries I work with tell me that this Chinese word translates into "glasses", but not "eye". Also, an internet image search for "眼镜" shows no eyes, but only glasses (and in another question, Duolingo uses the word "眼睛" for "eyes", which is at least inconsistent).

Could somebody please confirm that this is an error on Duolingo? I'd be happy with a very simple and short answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error confirmed. 眼镜 is glasses, 眼睛 is the eye, they are totally different things, as the pronunciations are very similar, one could mistype it easily with a pinyin input method.

Answer (score 1):

Pictorial keys - a) a green paint can, b) an ear, c) an eye with a glass, d) none of above

Q: Which one of these is "eye"?

A: "d"

The answer can be "c" if the question asks: "Which one of these **contains** "eye"?. Or there is no "d" and you can't leave the question unanswered.